# Importing a folder in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I'd like to import a folder to Xcode, not just the files it contains. The difference is that if the folder has files added to it later (ie., an update from a remote repository) then these files would automatically show on the project and be included in the build. What Xcode seems to be doing is just importing the **current** files on the directory. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode, the "folders" you see in the project navigator are "virtual" and need not even coincide with real folders on the disk (kind of a pain, if you ask me). Look in the toolbox pane for an xcode folder and you can see that you can associate it with a different disk folder. For example, in this image below I've renamed my "Chime" folder to "Boogies"....but the disk folder is still Chime. It will show as Boogies in the project, though.

[image: Sample mismatch]

As far as I've ever been able to tell, you have to tell XCode each file that should be included in a target...which it turns out is probably good, since you can have any number of build targets (e.g. test, production) which would not necessarily want the file.

Comment: I see. In this case I always want all files to be added, but I guess I'll just have to live with it

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know each file has to be added to each target. No way to get the folder to just "do it"

Comment: Well, I'm using external builds (makefiles), so I guess it won't make much of a difference. I did expect to get the file list from Xcode, though, so it's still a shame. Thank you for your help